# Inkscape: Unable to find verb ID 'AlignHorizontalLeft' specified on the command line

Tags: command-line-arguments, command-line-interface, inkscape

#### Version

```
inkscape --version
Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939 (Jan 22 2014)
```

I'm running the following `inkscape` command:

```
inkscape -f test.svg \
  --select=hanzi --verb=AlignHorizontalLeft --verb=EditDeselect \
  --select=pinyin --verb=AlignHorizontalRight --verb=EditDeselect \
  --select=hanzi --select=pinyin \
  --verb=AlignVerticalCenter --verb=SelectionUnion \
  --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit
```

And get the error:

```
Unable to find: AlignHorizontalLeft
Unable to find verb ID 'AlignHorizontalLeft' specified on the command line.
Unable to find: AlignHorizontalRight
Unable to find verb ID 'AlignHorizontalRight' specified on the command line.
Unable to find: AlignVerticalCenter
Unable to find verb ID 'AlignVerticalCenter' specified on the command line.
```

I can find related verbs when reading `inkscape --verbs-list` output.

What is the replacement for those verbs ? I need a solution as a cli command.

Answer (score 1):

From IRC channel `#inkscape`:

> ed8 | Any help for a replacement to the following verbs:
>   AlignHorizontalLeft, AlignHorizontalRight, AlignVerticalCenter in **0.48**
>   ?
>
> su_v | ed8: those verbs **only exist in trunk** (i.e. they will be available in the next major release)

So you need to install [using the PPA Inkscape trunk](https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/trunk).